# Wi-Fi connection to iPhone hotspot problem on MacBook Air

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, wifi

I just bought a used MacBook Air 2015.

Everything was okay until I tried to connect to my iPhone X hotspot.

- I cannot connect to it.
- I can connect to other Wi-Fi networks without any problem.
- I found a solution but it takes time and I don't like it.

I change my iPhone's name so it changes the hotspot's name too, I enter the password and everything is okay until I disconnect from my hotspot.

If I disconnect form it, I cannot connect to it. So I have to rename it again and connect it.

I have tried:

- Forgetting Wifi from settings and removing it from saved password
- Resetting PRAM
- Changing MTU

Other PCs and phones can connect to my hotspot without any problem and I know the problem is from my MacBook Air.
Currently I'm on Big Sur.

It's annoying to me to change my iPhone's name every time just to connect to it from my MacBook Air.

Comment: Did you try to just open the hotspot setting on th iPhone without modifications. It works for me when a device do not see the hotspot. Just opening the hotspot settings do the trick.

Comment: You can also try to connect with Bluetooth.

Comment: @PtitXav I did everything, but the problem is just with my Macbook air

Comment: @PtitXav Bluetooth is so slow and i want a fast connection

Comment: Did you try to setup hotspot in most compatible mode ? (It is an option in iOS 15  , I used to connect my car to My iPhone)

Comment: You can also connect via usb to iPhone. Could be best transfer speed.